# can't include path with qt creator on Windows 8

Tags: c++, qt, import, include

I'm new with Qt Creator. I'm trying to include a datapath wich contains a header file i have to use in my code. So i edit the .pro file in my project to add the path.

```
Win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/libraryDir/Include"
```

I tried with backslashes, without Win32 tag, without quotes, with a non-space path, etc and nothing works.
In my code i include file like this:

```
#include <file.h>
```

The error is: No such file or directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `file.h` in `C:/Program Files (x86)/libraryDir/Include` directory or in a sub directory. Please show the full path to the file.h.

Comment: C:/Program Files (x86)/libraryDir/Include/headerfile.h   Thank you

Comment: headerfile.h? But why do you include `#include <file.h>`? Shouldn't it be `#include <headerfile.h>`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I tried to say that the header file i want to use is in the Include folder. In code is `#include <headerfile.h>`

Comment: Have you tried to _run qmake_ after you modified the _.pro_ file? and of course with a path that doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that i have to run qmake before compiling. I though is an auto task when run build. Now, works well with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this running qmake after editing .pro file.